# Performance Issue (Nested Foreach Loops, Large Data Set)

Tags: php, arrays, performance, foreach, nested

I am working on an application for address standardization. I have a database table with 8000 rows, each row containing an address. My goal is to check each address against every other address in the database for a similar, but not exact match, and then output the results.

Currently, my approach is loading the 8000 rows into an array and using a nested foreach loop to pass the addresses to a function which will return true when a match is found (and stores the match in an array to output all matches after the loops).

The problem is, this is taking forever to load. Is this normally how you guys would approach this, or should I be looking for other solutions?

EXAMPLE: "123 garden st. ste. 140" should match "123 garden street suite 140", the database sorting idea is getting me thinking though..

All help is greatly appreciated!,
Trevor Kavanaugh

Comment: To follow Phil's answer, have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161359/not-distinct-query-in-mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `for` loop, as the `foreach` loop is resource intensive due to making a copy of the element on each interation. Though am I right in saying using your current nested loop method, you will be calling your matching method 8000^8000 times? This would also be quite intensive, another way you could do it is to query the database using a sort on the address field, therefore your matching algorithm would check if `array[i]` address is equal to `array[i+1]` and so forth, removing the need for nested loops

Comment: you know.. ive been sitting here rewriting and rewriting trying to make this faster, but that actually makes a lot of sense and I don't know how i missed it LOL... considering I am creating the array, then recreating it in the parent loop, then again in the child loop.. I dont even know why I used a foreach. Thanks man! I will post back in a few after I switch out my statements

Comment: It wouldn't be 8000^8000, cause you hopefully compare it to itself. You'd compare row 1 to 2-8000, row 2 to 3-8000

Comment: @RyanB, when the indexes are equal I do not compare. but it is still taking forever to run. the weird part is, all that happens in the body of the child loop is a call to one function, which currently only contains a few regex replace statements and always returns false. I understand there are 64,000,000 times that the loop is being executed, but damn..

Comment: If I understand the original post correctly, he is looking for a duplicates in the database, so you wouldn't be checking for itself, rather for a duplicate, so for each array item you would need to search the entire array

Comment: @andymccullough the main problem is, as i stated to the other answer, i am not looking for exact duplicates. the duplicates i am trying to locate are similar, but not exact :/

Comment: Sorting should still cluster similar elements close to each other, the work will have to go into analysing neighbouring array elements, your main problem is the 64m attempts at matching. You want to try and eliminate this

Comment: yah thats what I am realizing after thinking about what you guys have been telling me. I rewrote it into one loop and sorted by address, then I can compare each address vs the next one in the list.. Took me a little to grasp what you guys were getting at but its loading sooo much faster now, and its quite obvious why.. 64M loops vs 8000 loops :P

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to retrieve all the duplicate addresses directly from the database?

```
SELECT addressField
FROM tableName 
GROUP BY addressField 
HAVING COUNT (addressField)>0
```

That query should retrieve all the duplicate address in the database table.

You could then embed that query into a parent query to process duplicates, or simply output the results to an array.

Comment: this would be awesome, but I am actually looking for similar duplicated, not exact. for example, "123 garden st. ste. 140" should match up to "123 garden street suite 140"

Comment: Ah right, well I guess it is possible to do with fulltext searching, but I'd be a bit over complicated! Good luck :-)